# EKS Network Namespace, number of terminals

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, aws-cloud9

I'm going through a tutorial on EKS. The link says it will guide me through creating a network namespace in a Cloud9 host.

The first instruction says:

"

1. Open two terminals in the Cloud9 environment. Let’s refer them as Terminal 1 and Terminal 2.
2. Terminal 1 is referenced as the Container Terminal and Terminal 2 is the Host Terminal.
   " [Tutorial Link](https://awsk8snetworkshops.com/module1/networknamespace/)

So, what I have on AWS is a KOP container with Cloud9 and an EKS container with Cloud9.

Do I open one terminal from each?  Or do I open two KOP terminals? Or do I open two EKS terminals?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I was supposed to use only the KOP container's Cloud9.  And inside Cloud9, I was to open two terminals.